# XAML - move a label if text grows on a different label

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a label which has `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` so the width of the label will grow or shrink dependant on the text displayed. However, I want a label that is next to this label to move with the label dependant of its size. So basically if it grows, the two labels won't overlap. I have tried to play with the anchors on the view but with no success.

Anyone know what I can do?

Cheers

Comment: Can you use a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation and place the two labels inside?

Comment: Thanks @Krishna just tried that but with no luck. The code I written is seen in the main question

Comment: I think you probably got some set margins on the labels. Can you post the xaml of your labels please?

Comment: Actually, I was talking rubbish, I forgot to put a label inside the StackPanel so it worked, if you make it an answer I will mark it for you, for now I will rate your comment. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put those 2 labels inside a `StackPanel`(and set the `Orientation` to `Horizontal`) This should handle the spacing between the labels.